# Drawing tileset graphics to screen on paint event running slow

Tags: c#, performance, graphics, onpaint

as you may be able to tell from the code below I'm quite new to C#. For my first project (as a kind of test) I have made a 2D level editor, it has 5 layers. In the code below I am for-eaching through a shortlist dictionary which is generated everytime the map is changed and only contains the tiles which are filled, rather than using a for(x for(y for z(draw graphics))) which would have to check every part of the grid wether it had anything there or not.

It runs fine until i have about 30 tiles on the screen and then it starts running pretty slow, like really jerky. This paint event is only called when it needs to be, its not run on a timer, it purely runs when a new tile is laid, or the mouse cursor  is hovering over a new block. So i'm guessing the problem lies within the part where the image is actually drawn to the screen, like something is building up to much.

The line commented out below the DrawImage() function was to test if just drawing rectangles rather than a part of the tileset was faster. And it was!! I apologize for how nooby I may sound but please keep in mind that this is my first project and not really sure where to look for an answer on this specific subject.

Thanks!, heres my painting code below

```
public void editor_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        string[] keys;
        string[] values;

        foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> dict in map.shortlist){
            keys = dict.Key.Split('|');
            values = dict.Value.Split('|');
            int xpos = Convert.ToInt16(keys[0]);
            int ypos = Convert.ToInt16(keys[1]);
            int zpos = Convert.ToInt16(keys[2]);

            Tile tile = map.data[xpos, ypos, zpos];
            if (tile.type == "tile")
            {
                Bitmap img = tileset.bitmap.Clone(new Rectangle(tile.x * 16, tile.y * 16, 16, 16), tileset.bitmap.PixelFormat);
                g.DrawImage(img, new Point(xpos * 16, ypos * 16));                                       
                //g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Blue, new Rectangle(new Point(xpos * 16, ypos * 16), new Size(16,16)));                                       
            }
        }

        if (selector.MouseOver == true)
        {
            int tileSize = Preferences.blockSize;                
            Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 1);                
            g.DrawRectangle(pen, new Rectangle(new Point((MouseX / tileSize) * tileSize, (MouseY / tileSize) * tileSize), new Size(tileSize, tileSize)));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just an advice, a recommendation: if you are investing time in learning C# and .Net, I strongly suggest you leave winforms behind and learn any of the XAML-based technologies. winforms is quite useless compared to, say, WPF, when it comes to graphics. Also, its not hardware-accelerated, and thus has these performance problems you're experimenting right now. In WPF, you don't even need to deal with the things you written here. There's no `tile.x, tile.y, 16,16,16,etc,etc` because everything can be stretched to the container's size. Also, new technologies (WinRT) are all XAML-based.

Comment: @HighCore You're right somehow, but not completely. Windows Forms is a mature technology for desktop business applications. Besides grahics and facy animations, most of the time WPF is not suitable for LOB applications. Also it is easier to lear Windows Forms.

Comment: Thanks for your replies guys. In the end I managed to sort the problem by saving all of the tiles from the tileset into an array so they don't have to be pulled out on every iteration. Its really fast now! So what is the verdict on using WPF? When should I use Windows forms and when should I use WPF?

Comment: @MD.Unicorn sorry but I disagree completely. WPF provides a serious binding framework, and allows for things such as MVVM, which are more suitable for LOB than anything else in existence. Writing CRUD screens and DataGrids with advanced capabilities in WPF is clean and nice compared to the multiple hacks you need to do anything useful in winforms. WPF is not only about "fancy graphics" as you said, it's also about separation of View and logic, which winforms is uncapable of. WPF has much better performance, and built-in UI virtualization, so it is faster when dealing with large collections

Comment: @MD.Unicorn please go ahead and show me one use case where winforms is more suitable than WPF. Also, WPF 4.0 is as mature as winforms. The learning curve is surely steeper, but in the end WPF is simpler because in MVVM you almost never to manipulate UI elements in code. [This is an example of a WPF LOB, which is impossible in winforms](http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=115)

Comment: @Zephni clearly WPF. winforms is a dinosaur and is not even recommended for new projects anymore. If you need to maintain an old application it's ok. but all new Microsoft technologies are XAML-based. They just released WinRT last year, and it's XAML-based, not winforms based.

Comment: Thanks very much for your advice guys, looks like I got off on the wrong foot, I should be 'investing' my time in learning the more current technology that is WPF. I'll be starting my project again, but I don't mind as it was pretty much for learning C# anyway, I might aswell quit while I'm ahead and start with WPF!

Comment: @zephni winforms developers will tell you to go with winforms because they're just used to it. they managed to hack their ways into doing something useful with it, but the reality is that WPF is much better, more scalable, more performant, easier to maintain, and allows a true and clear separation between application logic and UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone was having similar performance issues I will answer this question in a round about way, thanks to the guys below in the comments for pointing some things out to me.

The line causing the problem is most probably quite obvious:

```
Bitmap img = tileset.bitmap.Clone(new Rectangle(tile.x * 16, tile.y * 16, 16, 16), tileset.bitmap.PixelFormat);
```

It is having to create a new bitmap on every foreach when it comes across a tile and select a square from the original tileset bitmap. Doing this a 30-40 times is rather labour intensive.

So instead I just cached all of the tiles into an array when the tileset is first loaded, like this:

```
    private void GenerateBitmapTiles() {
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(TilesetImageFile);

        bitmaps = new Bitmap[image.Width / 16, image.Height / 16];
        for (int x = 0; x < image.Width / 16; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < image.Height / 16; y++)
            {
                bitmaps[x, y] = bitmap.Clone(new Rectangle(x * 16, y * 16, 16, 16), bitmap.PixelFormat);
            }
        }

        bitmap.Dispose();
    }
```

Then I could just pull in the tiles by doing:

```
g.DrawImage(bitmap[x, y], new Point(xpos * 16, ypos * 16));
```

BUT! After reading the comments below I have realised that winforms is older technology.. Winforms isn't obsolete, but WPF is more recent technology and can perform a lot better under stress, plus its hardware accelerated.

I have started to rebuild the project in WPF, and painting just isn't an issue. Rather than saying: here is my data, now every time then screen paints I want to draw this object here here and here, In WPF you just say, I want my object here, here and here. The rest is done by WPF itself.